# Delete an alias and index in elastic search

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, alias

I am working on elastic search and I have the following situation.

1. I have two indices index1 and index2.
2. Alias1 points to index1 and index2.
3. Alias2 points to index2.

I would like to delete all of them. Do I need to delete index1, index2 and then delete aliases ? Will the aliases exist if I delete both the indices ? If they exist, what are the java API's to delete those aliases ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you have deleted your index, the alias will also get deleted.

In your case, you can directly delete index1 and index2.

Note: I've experimented it in ES 1.7

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete your Alias not index then first delete the Alias and then Index